# Csh Variable declaration

Tags: csh

Unable to echo $varible_$variable in csh

set a = temp

set value_${a} = 10

when trying to print the variable it isn't working. I need this to implement in nested for loop.

echo $value_$a
value_: Undefined variable. (**working with $value_temp**)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use eval, with escape of the first `$` when reading a variable:

```
% set a = temp
% eval set var_${a}=10
% echo $var_temp
10
% eval echo \$var_$a
10
% eval set result=\$var_$a
% echo $result
10
```